# Differences between R's and Numpy's QR decomposition

Tags: python, r, numpy

I'm working through a large R (v3.6.0) codebase and trying to understand what it is doing.  To do this, I'm translating some of the R code into Python (v3.6.5) using Numpy (v1.14.3).  I have a piece of R code that appears to work just fine:

```
> v<-c(1,1,1,1)
> qrout<-qr(v)
> qr.Q(qrout)
     [,1]
[1,] -0.5
[2,] -0.5
[3,] -0.5
[4,] -0.5
> qr.R(qrout)
     [,1]
[1,]   -2
```

The Python equivalent is **not** fine :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v=np.ones(4)
>>> v
array([1., 1., 1., 1.])
>>> np.linalg.qr(v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 753, in qr
    _assertRank2(a)
  File "/opt/python/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 195, in _assertRank2
    'two-dimensional' % a.ndim)
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: 1-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional
```

Looking at the docs it appears that in R uses LAPACK's `DQRDC(2)`/`DGEQP3`/`ZGEQP3`, while Numpy uses LAPACK's `dgeqrf`, `zgeqrf`, `dorgqr`, and `zungqr`.  Clearly R is happy with a 1 dimensional matrix, while Numpy is not.

**QUESTION**

How do I replicate R's QR factorization using Numpy?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the error message

> Array must be two-dimensional

```
In [7]: qr(v[:,None])                                                                     
Out[7]: 
(array([[-0.5],
        [-0.5],
        [-0.5],
        [-0.5]]), array([[-2.]]))
```

*Edit*
<sup>What follows is not different from the striked code above, but who knows...</sup>

```
In [28]: from numpy.linalg import qr 
    ...: from numpy import ones

In [29]: v = ones(4) ; print(v.shape) ; print(v[:,None].shape) # adding a dimension
(4,)
(4, 1)

In [30]: q, r = qr(v[:, None])

In [31]: print(q) ; print() ; print(r)                 
[[-0.5]
 [-0.5]
 [-0.5]
 [-0.5]]

[[-2.]]

In [32]:
```

In Python/Numpy arrays can have just one dimension, but `qr` requires a 2-dimensional array.

E.g., in Python transposition doesn't modify the dimensions of what is, in its essence, a 1D vector.

```
In [9]: print(v); print(v.T)                                                              
[1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1]

[10]: print(v.shape); print((v.T).shape)                                                
(4,)
(4,)
```

In R, `qr()` attempts to coerce its input to a 2-dimensional array (matrix), so `qr()` does this step for you, while in Python you have to do it explicitly.

<sup>The most idiomatic way to add a dimension to a Numpy array being to use `None` in a slice object to signify the addition of a dummy dimension to it.</sup>

Comment: @Gregor Thank you for the clarification. I've installed R tonight... I have to say that when I saw `dim(v)` printing `NULL` I was a little bit puzzled. I have tried to edit my answer following your advice.

Comment: It seems that `np.ones(4)` yields a row vector, `np.ones([4,1])` yields a column vector.  The row vector fails (see question above), the column vector succeeds (albeit different from R's qr factorization).  How does that fit into your answer?

Comment: _@irritable_phd_syndrom "`np.ones(4)` yields a row vector"_ Sorry but it does not, it yields a 1D array, a row vector is a 2D array, with `1` row and `N` columns (please have a look at the example with the transpose, when I started with Numpy I had a hard time understanding this). ֎ ֎ ֎ In which sense the results of Numpy are different? I see `[-1/2,-1/2,-1/2,-1/2]` and `[-2]` in both cases... ֎ ֎ ֎  Fit in my answer? Could you please expand?

Comment: Please, show the example of running this running successfully in Python and I'll accept it as an answer.